# Two Queries into one table with two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

I have a table named Rooms that looks like this

#### rooms

```
id    name   room number 
-------------------------
1     Dave   Room 100  
2     NULL   ROOM 101    
3     Scott  Room 100
```

I need to check which room is empty and which room has people associated with it so the result is going to be :

```
Room name  Count        
-----------------
Room 100   2      -- Because Dave and Scott is in the room
Room 101   0      -- No name is associated with the room
```

I just started learning SQL so my knowledge is limited What i can see is

```
SELECT Count(room_number) 
  FROM rooms 
 WHERE name != NULL
```

...will return 2 and 0 based on times of room_number shows up in a list and the name associated with it is not 0 and also

```
SELECT DISTINCT(room_number) 
  FROM rooms
```

...will return Room 100 and Room 101 once

How can I combine these two queries to give me the result table that I want?

Answer (score 4):

```
SELECT RoomNumber, COUNT(Name)
FROM rooms
GROUP BY RoomNumber
```

I would recommend adding a `Room` table and changing `RoomNumber` to a foreign key relationship. Normalize that column.

Comment: This will show `1` for `Room 101`. Perhaps `COUNT(name)` instead.

Comment: oh wow that worked like a charm Thanks so much for the fast reply but I will look into the adding a Room table but this will do for now thanks a bunch.

Comment: Wrong result with count(id), wrong column names, why this answer is upvoted so much?

Comment: It was upvoted before he fixed it, when it was a really bad answer.

Comment: I was surprised too that it had 3 votes before. But it was not really bad even then. It showed that `GROUP By` is the key to the solution and there was also a suggestion for normalization.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(NAME), RoomNumber
FROM ROOMS
GROUP BY RoomNumber
```